# How to change background color when a variable is negative?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to change the background color of a styled div to red when variable totalNetworkScore is negative.

Comment: Currently I have "background: green;". I just don't know what statement I would use to turn the background to red when a variable has a value under 0.

Comment: How are you setting the background color? Are you doing it with pure CSS? Are you doing it in a component template? Where is the variable located?

Comment: I am using react. The variable is located earlier in the file. I am setting the background color through a styled div. (const NetworkScore = styled.div`)

Comment: I would recommend you to use styled-components. Using it you can pass props to your style and it becomes really easy to do a change similar to the one that you intend to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a [ternary operator](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/c/ternary-operator/) to set conditional classes.

```
:class="{{totalNetworkScore ? 'green' : 'red'}}"
```

in css:

```
.green {
    background: green;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: No your initial answer was great. I ended up implementing it directly into the "background: " by declaring another variable that had a true or false value. The value would change whenever totalNetworkScore dipped under 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @emotion/core library and do something like this:

```
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import React from "react";

checkNegative = counter => {
  if (counter) {
    return css`
      background: green;
    `;
  }
};

class Component extends React.Component {
  state = { counter: -1 };
  render() {
    return <div css={checkNegative(this.state.counter)}>some text</div>;
  }
}

export default Component;
```